# Default Gems for Rails (Minimum needed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want to clean up my development server.  I know there are a ton of gems installed that I do not need.  I can't seem to find a list anywhere of the default, or minimum gems that Rails normally installs for its self.  If someone can help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new app, you could pull the gems that it defaults to the Gemfile.

Comment: Okay, the only reason I don't trust that is I remember installing a specific gem, and that was automatically included in a new project I just generated.  Is there way way at all that a gem can auto include its self like that?  Or am I just going crazy and that gem was installed from the start? (This is entirely possible).

Comment: I've never experienced this and haven't heard about it happening. What was the gem called?

Comment: it was the jquery-rails gem.  I had installed it before jquery became the default js library.  I was going to use jquery anyway but it confused me when I didn't have to specify it as I normally had to.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I was not going crazy, the gem I had installed became a default in the newest version of rails. I did have a clean environment after all.